# How can I "conditionally" join text from 2 or more textFields into a single textView?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I "*conditionally*" join text from 2 or more textFields into a single textView ?

I cant seem to find a way to do this, is it even possible

(conditionally meaning - join only the text|Fields that have been selected by way of switches)

I am using userDefaults and iOS switches as shown in my below code.

**ViewController2 (source)**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var switchON : Bool = false
    @IBAction func checkState(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if Switch1.isOn{
            switchON = true
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switch1ON")
        }
        if Switch1.isOn == false{
            switchON = false
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switch1ON")
        }
        if Switch2.isOn{
            switchON = true
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switch2ON")
        }
        if Switch2.isOn == false{
            switchON = false
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switch2ON")
```

**ViewController1 (destination)**

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  // Select Comments -----------------------------------
        if defaults.value(forKey: "switch1ON") != nil{
            let switch1ON: Bool = defaults.value(forKey: "switch1ON")  as! Bool
            if switch1ON == true{
                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                Reference.text = userDefaults.value(forKey: "PredefinedText1") as? String
            }

        if defaults.value(forKey: "switch2ON") != nil{
            let switch2ON: Bool = defaults.value(forKey: "switch2ON")  as! Bool
            if switch2ON == true{
                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                Reference.text = userDefaults.value(forKey: "PredefinedText2") as? String
            }
           // else if switch1ON == false{
            //    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            //    Reference.text = userDefaults.value(forKey: "") as? String
            //}
        }
        }
```

Comment: FYI - you should not be using UserDefaults just to pass data between view controllers.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, what is the reason for that ? I dont know any other way at this stage

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?r=SearchResults&s=1|392.6186 for better options of passing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you should not use `UserDefaults` to pass data between controllers, here are some things you need to fix in your code.

Your four `if` statements in `ViewController2` can be replaced with these two lines:

```
defaults.set(switch1.isOn, forKey: "switch1ON")
defaults.set(switch2.isOn, forKey: "switch2ON")
```

In `ViewController1` there is a much simpler way to get the two settings:

```
let switch1ON = defaults.bool(forKey: "switch1ON")
let switch2ON = defaults.bool(forKey: "switch2ON")
```

Don't use `value(forKey:)` unless you have a clearly understood need to use key-value coding.

Then get the two strings:

```
let text1 = userDefaults.string(forKey: "PredefinedText1")
let text2 = userDefaults.string(forKey: "PredefinedText2")
```

There are several ways to code the logic for conditionally combing the strings. Here's on way:

```
var textVals = [String]()
if let text1 = text1, switch1ON {
    textVals.append(text1)
}
if let text2 = text2, switch2ON {
    textVals.append(text2)
}

Results.text = textVals.joined(separator: " ")
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy, I’ll fix my code per your recommendations and if solved will tick your answer. I really appreciate your assistance too, thanks

Comment: Thanks Maddy, i just fixed my code per your recommendations, works perfectly, i just have to make 1 adjustment to your code, was a typo on the switch name - "switch21ON" should be "switch1ON" - but all good now - Thanks so much